# Problema con autocomplete de jQueriUI this.source is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

Tengo un problema aplicando el módulo de *autocompletar* de **jQueryUI**. Me envía un error diciendo "this.source is not a function". Estoy trabajando con **jQuery** y **AngularJS**. Estoy usando **JQuery 2.1.4**, **JQueryUI 1.11.2** y **Angular 1.3**

Acá dejo el código **HTML** y **JS**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Base</title>
  <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/autocomplete-jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
  <style>
   .circular
   {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
   }

   .no-list li
   {
    list-style-type: none;
   }

   html, body
   {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" my-autocomplete="posts" placeholder="Buscar repositorio">
  <ul class="no-list">
   <li ng-repeat="repo in posts" ng-hide="main_repo && main_repo != repo.name">
   <!-- <img ng-src="{{repo.owner.avatar_url}}" alt="" class="circular"> -->
    <!-- <div class="circular" style="background-image: url({{repo.owner.avatar_url}}); background-position: center; background-size: cover;"></div> -->
    <div class="circular" back-img="{{repo.owner.avatar_url}}">

    </div>
    <h1>{{repo.name}}</h1>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.directive('myAutocomplete', function()
{
 return function link(scope, element, attrs)
 {
  $(element).autocomplete(
  {
   source: scope.$eval(attrs.myAutocomplete),
   select: function(ev, ui)
   {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if(ui.item)
    {
     scope.optionSelected(ui.item.value);
    }
   },
   focus: function(ev, ui)
   {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
   }
  });
 };

 return
 {
  link: link
 };
})
.directive('backImg', function()
{
 return function(scope, element, attrs)
 {
  attrs.$observe('backImg', function(value)
  {
   element.css({
    "background": "url('"+value+"')",
    "background-size": "cover",
    "background-position": "center"
   });
  });
 };
})
.controller("myController", function($scope, $http)
{
 $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/twitter/repos")
 .success(function(data)
 {
  $scope.posts = data;

  for(var i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
   var repo = data[i];
   $scope.posts.push(repo.name);
  }
 })
 .error(function(err)
 {
  console.log(err);
 });

 $scope.optionSelected = function(data)
 {
  $scope.apply(function()
  {
   $scope.main_repo = data;
  })
 };
});
```

Comment: ¿En qué línea del código te da el error?¿Podrias crear un [mcve] para reproducir el problema?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEMA:
ufff fácil muy fácil eso pasa porque el modelo "$scope.posts = data;" actúa como una variable privada del controlador "mycontroller" ya que es una respuesta de callback de una petición a un repositorio de twitter, en otras palabras en la directiva personalizada "myAutocomplete", el "source" esta solicitando una fuente de información pero como tu variable modelo "$scope.posts = data;" es privada no puede acceder a ella.

SOLUCIÓN: para convertir la variable modelo "$scope.posts = data;" privada en una variable publica y asi posteriormente poder enviarla a la directiva personalizada se declara esta variable iniciandola afuera del callback del GET

```
.controller("myController", function($scope, $http){
$scope.repositorio = [];
    $http({method:'GET',url:'https://api.github.com/users/twitter/repos'})
    .then(function(success){ 
        $scope.posts = success.data;
        for (var i = success.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var repo = success.data[i];
            $scope.repositorio.push(repo.name);
        }   
    }
    ,function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```